# Team selection combinations problem

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can a team of 9 softball players be selected from 15 trying out, if 3 are experienced and....

b. Find the probability that there is at least one experienced player on the team.

c. Once the team is chosen, how many selections of 2 pitchers, 2 catchers, and 5
outfielders are possible?

I honestly have tried different things but I don't seem to be getting it.

Comment: What are the different things you have tried?

Comment: I tried to use the additive counting principle

Comment: Are there any constraints on the pitchers, catchers and outfielders or are all players assumed to be capable of any role?

Comment: They are all considered to be capable of playing any role!

Comment: You should really *show* some of the different things you tried so that we might help point out how and where you were going awry.  It is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Part (b) is a case where the negative space is more easy to calculate: the probability that there are **no** experienced players.

The unconstrained choice has [$\binom {15}{9}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $ = \frac{\large 15!}{\large 9!6!} = \frac{\large 15\cdot14 \cdot13 \cdot12 \cdot11 \cdot10}{\large 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$ $ = 5005$ options.

The no-experienced-players choice has $\binom {12}{9} = \frac{\large 12!}{\large 9!3!} =\frac{\large 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10}{\large 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 220$ options.

So the probability of having an experienced player on the team from a blind choice is $\frac{\large 5005-220}{\large 5005}$ $ = \frac{\large 4785}{\large 5005}$ $ = \frac{\large 87}{\large 91}$

Part (c) potentially depends on player skill mix, but absent any constraint will be [$\binom {9}{2,2,5}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials) $ = \binom  92\binom 72$

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Im going to try this method on the next example, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Click the checkmark if you have all the information you need from this.